# Unsupported locale setting despite installation

Tags: python, locale

I'm running linux ubuntu 22.04.3. I've already verified that the locale names are correct and that they are installed on my system. This code was run on jupyter notebook.

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,('de_DE.utf8','UTF-8'))

print(locale.getlocale())


Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[65], line 6
      1 import locale
      3 #locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,('de_de','de_DE.ISO8859-1'))
      4 
      5 #locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'de_DE.utf8')
----> 6 locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,('de_DE.utf8','UTF-8'))
      8 print(locale.getlocale())

File ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/locale.py:626, in setlocale(category, locale)
    623 if locale and not isinstance(locale, _builtin_str):
    624     # convert to string
    625     locale = normalize(_build_localename(locale))
--> 626 return _setlocale(category, locale)

Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: Can you run `locale -a` (e.g. via the `!` bang magic, `!locale -a`, in a Jupyter cell)? That should show you the locales that should be available.

Comment: Just tried this. As expected 'de_DE.utf8' is already available.

Comment: Can you set the locale in Python if you run the Python REPL in a terminal?

Answer (score 0):

> `locale` may be a string, or an iterable of two strings (language code and encoding)

says [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale); you're passing in a language-code-with-encoding and an encoding.

Try

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('de_DE', 'utf8'))
```

or

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.utf8')
```

?

Comment: Both return the same error message reported in the above question.